# Behavior monitoring feature of Client Security Agent?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm a university student, and in order to use the campus wifi, need to install CSA.  However, I'm unfamilliar with it, so out of curiosity, did a bit of research to see what it was, and noticed that it has a behavior monitoring feature.  What, exactly, does this mean?  Does it (or any other features of CSA since a couple others seemed as if they apply to this question, too) allow administrators to access my activity?  While I don't think they would be concerned by any of my activity and it's not a problem per se, it does feel like somewhat of an invasion of privacy if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

“Behavior monitoring” in a security product, typically refers to heuristics detections. Instead of relying on a fixed set of digital signatures of known infections, a heuristics detection engine can find and eliminate previously unseen malware that is “behaving” maliciously.

We are not able to know exactly which product you are referring to, and several products over the years have used similar terminology.

You should’ve been given a disclaimer to accept before installing the product and it would’ve detailed what the application will do, especially in regards to privacy. This, or the University has a corresponding document available for you to read.

I suggest you contact your University’s support desk for further clarification about what the product does and to address your concerns.